How to save elementor files in Child theme to override the main files
I've made layout adjustments to the following files:

/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/woocommerce/module.php
/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/woocommerce/wc-templates/cart/mini-cart.php

I'd like to preserve these files, possibly by placing them in a child theme, to prevent future updates to Elementor PRO from affecting my layout. Could you advise me on how to properly save these files in a child theme?
I attempted to save these files in the plugin directory of the Hello Elementor child theme, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired outcome. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this?
I just want to add some extra widgets to my menu cart. See the attached screenshots:
This is the default Elementor Menu Cart
This is how I want to make Elementor Menu Cart to look like

Template files can usually be overwritten by placing a copy in the right location in the child theme, but actual classes / functions can't be overwritten that easily. Your question lacks details on what exactly you need to modify, so it is currently hard to say, if there might be a way. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72045735/1427878 does something via hooks provided by Elementor, maybe what you need to change offers something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33147735/1427878 has some more general info on overwriting plugin functionality in certain scenarios.

Elementor Menu Cart comes only with Items in the cart. I want to add a section with 3 random products, A header with heading on the top and a Image for Payment methods supported by the website.
I have created a template with above features in Elementor Saved Templates and now I want to show that section in the Menu Cart using Shortcode.
That's why I have edited the mini-cart.php & module.php file
